# How do I make a function that returns a list of unique strings, given a list of strings with duplicates?

Tags: python, list, unique, python-3.3

This is a piece of homework for my programming course. We are asked to make a function that accepts a list of strings as a parameter, and then returns the same list of strings but without duplicates.
                               e.g:

```
>>> unique_list(['dog','cat','dog','fish'])
['dog','cat','fish']
```

Any information regarding the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the order in which you return the strings matter?

Comment: First time using this website, was not dissapointed, this is an excellent resource. Thank you to all who helped me in answering this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
>>> def unique_list(mylist):
...     copy = []
...     for k in mylist:
...             if k not in copy:
...                     copy.append(k)
...     return copy
... 
>>> unique_list([1])
[1]
>>> unique_list([1, 1])
[1]
>>> unique_list([1, 1, 2])
[1, 2]
>>> unique_list([1, 3, 1, 2])
[1, 3, 2]
>>> unique_list(['dog','cat','dog','fish'])
['dog', 'cat', 'fish']
```

The `for` loop loops over every item in `mylist`. If the item is already in `copy`, it does nothing. Otherwise, it adds the item to copy. At the end, we return the 'unduplicatified' version of `mylist`, stored in `copy`.

Or a one-liner would be:

```
>>> def unique_list(mylist):
...     return list(set(mylist))
... 
>>> unique_list([1])
[1]
>>> unique_list([1, 1])
[1]
>>> unique_list([1, 1, 2])
[1, 2]
>>> unique_list([1, 3, 1, 2])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> unique_list(['dog','cat','dog','fish'])
['fish', 'dog', 'cat']
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful information. I see I was missing the `append` option in my trials, now I can play around with it. Also, that `set` function looks incredibly useful aswell, will definently give that a go.

Comment: Glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def unique_list(subject):
    return list(set(subject))
```

This is what you can write in python 3.3

Comment: Oops, now I see @aj8uppal already mentioned it in the lower section of his answer. :(